# Understanding Builder Pattern in C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, builder-pattern

**Definition of Builder Pattern:**
The Builder pattern separates the specification of a complex object from its actual
construction. The same construction process can create different representations.

well i have a code sample of Builder Pattern like this

```
class Director
    {
        // Build a Product from several parts
        public void Construct(IBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.BuildPartA();
            builder.BuildPartB();
            builder.BuildPartB();
        }
    }

    interface IBuilder
    {
        void BuildPartA();
        void BuildPartB();
        Product GetResult();
    }

    class Builder1 : IBuilder
    {
        private Product product = new Product();
        public void BuildPartA()
        {
            product.Add("PartA ");
        }

        public void BuildPartB()
        {
            product.Add("PartB ");
        }

        public Product GetResult()
        {
            return product;
        }
    }

    class Builder2 : IBuilder
    {
        private Product product = new Product();
        public void BuildPartA()
        {
            product.Add("PartX ");
        }

        public void BuildPartB()
        {
            product.Add("PartY ");
        }

        public Product GetResult()
        {
            return product;
        }
    }

    class Product
    {
        List<string> parts = new List<string>();
        public void Add(string part)
        {
            parts.Add(part);
        }

        public void Display()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nProduct Parts -------");
            foreach (string part in parts)
                Console.Write(part);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    public class Client
    {

        public static void Main()
        {
            // Create one director and two builders
            Director director = new Director();

            IBuilder b1 = new Builder1();
            IBuilder b2 = new Builder2();

            // Construct two products
            director.Construct(b1);
            Product p1 = b1.GetResult();
            p1.Display();

            director.Construct(b2);
            Product p2 = b2.GetResult();
            p2.Display();

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
```

Now, i have made some changes in the above code. Is the below code still represent a Builder Pattern?

```
class Director
    {
        public void Construct(IBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.BuildPartA();
            builder.BuildPartB();
            builder.GetResult();
        }
    }

    interface IBuilder
    {
        void BuildPartA();
        void BuildPartB();
        void GetResult();
    }

    class Builder1 : IBuilder
    {
        List<string> product = new List<string>();
        public void BuildPartA()
        {
            product.Add("PartA ");
        }

        public void BuildPartB()
        {
            product.Add("PartB ");
        }

        public void GetResult()
        {
            foreach (var p in product)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("the product created is :" + p);
            }
        }
    }

    class Builder2 : IBuilder
    {
        List<string> product = new List<string>();
        public void BuildPartA()
        {
            product.Add("PartX ");
        }

        public void BuildPartB()
        {
            product.Add("PartY ");
        }

        public void GetResult()
        {
            foreach (var p in product)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("the product created is :" + p);
            }
        }
    }
    public class Client
    {

        public static void Main()
        {

            Director director = new Director();
            IBuilder b1 = new Builder1();
            IBuilder b2 = new Builder2();
            director.Construct(b1);
            director.Construct(b2);

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
```

**note:**

> I have removed the product class from the second sample code.

My question is, creating a class which handles all the object and call the method in a orderly fashion makes it a Builder Pattern? Just wanted to make sure that I understood the concept of Builder Pattern.
Thanks in advance

**UPDATE 1**

i really couldn't understand why the second sample is not a Builder Pattern. Let me create a second example which would be simple for me to understand and would be simple for others to help me understand. The below is the code.

```
 interface IRoutine {
        void WakeUp();
        void GoToSchool();
        void ListenToMusic();
        void Sleep();
    }
    class person1 : IRoutine
    {
        public void GoToSchool()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("going to school");
        }

        public void ListenToMusic()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("litening to music");
        }

        public void Sleep()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("tring to sleep");
        }

        public void WakeUp()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("good morning !!!");
        }
    }
    class person2 : IRoutine
    {
        public void GoToSchool()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("going to school");
        }

        public void ListenToMusic()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("litening to music");
        }

        public void Sleep()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("tring to sleep");
        }

        public void WakeUp()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("good morning !!!");
        }
    }
    class Builder {
        public void Construct(IRoutine routine) {
            routine.WakeUp();
            routine.GoToSchool();
            routine.ListenToMusic();
            routine.Sleep();
        }
    }
    class Client {
        static void Main() {
            Builder builder = new Builder();
            IRoutine r1 = new person1();
            IRoutine r2 = new person2();

            builder.Construct(r1);
            builder.Construct(r2);

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
```

Is the recent example which i have provided a Builder Pattern? If not then why it is not a Builder Pattern, please help me understand.

Comment: "fulfills the criteria of Builder Pattern" I think your thinking about patterns the wrong way. There is no such criteria a pattern is more a guideline then something you could run an static code analyzer that will tell you this is or is not a "Builder Pattern".

Comment: @FilipCordas sorry, what i wanted to ask you is, is the second example which i  have provided you is a Builder Pattern? I just wanted to be sure for myself that i have learned the Builder Pattern, thats all... thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your latter snippet is not an example of the builder pattern. The step where you *create* the final object is the crucial part of the pattern, and by removing that step your builder class effectively becomes the actual, constructed (mutable) object. In other words, if `string` was mutable, there wouldn't exist a `StringBuilder`, you would just use a hypothetical `string.Append` method to mutate the end object. Or, if `StringBuilder` returned anything other than a constructed `string`, it wouldn't be called a `StringBuilder`.

To justify the existence of a builder in practice, I would expect it either to:

1. Provide a interface for building an immutable object, and then "freeze" it, i.e. return an *immutable* built instance (`StringBuilder` is a good example).
2. Provide a slightly cleaner (e.g. fluent) interface for instantiating an object, compared so, say, having a huge number of constructor parameters. If the end object is mutable, however, it makes it harder to justify this, since you can set individual properties anyway.

Some examples use the builder to provide an additional layer of abstraction for building an object (i.e. allow different concrete types to be built in the same way), and then pass the abstract builder to a "director" which uses it to build the object, but I find this step irrelevant to the pattern. I would even go a step further and say that abstract builders with several methods feel like an antipattern, because they tie the construction of each concrete object to the same building process. To understand my point better, think how you would implement `BoatBuilder` in the example given [here](http://www.dofactory.com/net/builder-design-pattern).

Comment: i couldn't understand the example which you have given, I have updated a new example, could you please go through it an help me understand the Builder Pattern.... thank you:)

Comment: In the first snippet, you have a `GetResult` method which returns a `Product` instance.  This is why it's called the builder pattern, because it *builds* the `Product`, so `Builder1` and `Builder2` are builders. In the 2nd snippet, you changed the method into a `void` method, meaning this method doesn't return anything, and in turn meaning that the class *doesn't build* anything, but instead mutates itself. The third example is even farther away, because the `IRoutine` interface doesn't even have a `GetResult` method, and you renamed the `Director` into a `Builder`.

Comment: In other words, you don't need a director, this is optional for this pattern. Forget about the implementation and concentrate on what the builder is supposed to do. `StringBuilder` is a perfect example of a builder. 1) You create a new `StringBuilder`, 2) You use `Append` methods to mutate the builder, and 3) You call the `StringBuilder.ToString()` method to finalize construction and return the immutable result. A bunch of methods writing to the `Console` are not building anything, the most important lines in the initial snippet are `product.Add(*)` and `return product`.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO this is an implementation of the builder pattern. The only fundamental difference between your implementation and the example you provided is the type of the "product". In your implementation you are making a concatenated string (I'm sure you know there are simpler ways to do this!) but the sample builds an object of type "Product".

What you use the builder pattern to construct is not really a relevant factor when determining whether you are using the builder pattern or not.

The builder pattern can be used to separate the construction of a complex object from its representation. I wouldn't class a string as a complex object that deserves implementing such complex code but you are still using a builder.

I agree with the comment left by Filip Cordas, if you know how to build your sample code you then have the power to adapt it to fit your needs. This is the power of knowing design patterns. Whether another developer agrees that your adaptation is or is not a "pure" implementation of the builder pattern is irrelevant; you've hopefully got some well designed code that meets your needs.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion this is not a builder pattern but can be changed simply to be. 
Right now the only thing you are building is the builder it self. What I think would make it a "proper" builder pattern is changing your GetResult method to:

```
public List<string> GetResult()
        {
           return product;
        }
```

This way you are building a list of strings inside of your IBuilder(This is a general rule usually when you do a copy paste means you might want to rethink you implementation). The names can give you a clue your get method is not getting anything but in fact printing. But to me you implementation dose something much worse it violates the [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). Right now you class can change if you want to change your build process or want a new way of displaying it where as the first implementation has only one.